# Datacompy library: how to save report string into a Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-comparison

I need to save the report in `.xlsx` format.

I'm comparing between two data frames using Datacompy, but how can I save the final result as an Excel sheet. How can I save it as a Excel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.